# Postfix email delivery problems - yahoodns

Tags: centos, email, postfix

Looking for a little advice. We seem to be blocked by yahoo but I can't find anywhere online that provides a method to requesting unblocking.

I should stress that port 25 is open (other emails are delivered OK) and that we are not on any blocklists (see image).
[blocklist test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfnb.jpg)

```
Aug 2 05:01:30 plesk postfix/smtp[32030]: connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 2 05:01:30 plesk postfix/smtp[32030]: ED64E6694E: to=<r**4@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=242195, delays=242165/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30755]: connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30755]: 960F26884A: to=<n**s@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=309573, delays=309543/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30754]: connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30753]: connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30754]: 2619B62386: to=<g**y@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=193666, delays=193636/0.06/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out)
Aug 2 05:06:30 plesk postfix/smtp[30753]: AB25C665DF: to=<c**5@yahoo.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=126501, delays=126471/0.09/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net[188.125.69.79]:25: Connection timed out)
```

This is just a tiny example of all the delayed emails.

I can't ping mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net and it looks like we might have been blacklisted but our IP comes back clean on all the automated RBL's we've tried.

There are a couple of other timeouts for apparently non-yahoo addresses:

```
Aug 2 05:26:29 plesk postfix/smtp[4114]: connect to hmrc.co.uk[195.171.114.178]:25: Connection timed out
Aug 2 05:26:29 plesk postfix/smtp[4114]: B8B886A023: to=<no-reply@hmrc.co.uk>, relay=none, delay=312205, delays=312175/0.03/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to hmrc.co.uk[195.171.114.178]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Can anyone suggest how we might go about fixing this - or even what the problem might be?!

Many thanks

Traceroute looks like this:

```
[root@plesk httpdocs]# traceroute 188.125.69.79
traceroute to 188.125.69.79 (188.125.69.79), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  xxx (x.x.x.x)  0.584 ms  0.622 ms  0.960 ms
 2  77.243.179.213 (77.243.179.213)  8.500 ms  8.518 ms  8.534 ms
 3  te-6-2-0.core-dc1.man4.uk.m247.com (77.243.176.105)  0.293 ms  0.355 ms  0.391 ms
 4  te8-7-0.bb1.lon2.uk.m247.com (77.243.179.29)  8.241 ms  8.297 ms  8.327 ms
 5  ge-1-1-0.pat1.the.yahoo.com (195.66.224.129)  8.451 ms  8.501 ms  8.452 ms
 6  so-0-0-0.pat1.irz.yahoo.com (66.196.65.33)  18.054 ms UNKNOWN-66-196-65-X.yahoo.com (66.196.65.17)  25.527 ms so-0-0-0.pat1.irz.yahoo.com (66.196.65.33)  18.002 ms
 7  ae-1.msr1.ird.yahoo.com (66.196.67.231)  21.516 ms ae-2.msr2.ird.yahoo.com (66.196.67.237)  48.834 ms  21.557 ms
 8  ae-0.msr2.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.133)  18.552 ms ae-0.msr1.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.129)  31.610 ms ae-1.msr1.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.131)  22.041 ms
 9  et-17-9.bas2-1-prd.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.145)  32.953 ms et-18-17.bas2-1-prd.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.147)  26.275 ms et-17-17.bas1-1-prd.ir2.yahoo.com (217.146.185.176)  22.335 ms
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
[root@plesk httpdocs]#
```

Comment: That's not how Yahoo do rate limiting.  When they do, you will see something like `status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.33] refused to talk to me: 
421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 192.0.2.5 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)`. You have network connection issues.

Comment: Hello Ladadadada - how would I work out if these are local to our machine or datacentre (dns resolver) issues?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RBLs are not the only means of blacklisting an IP. Email providers use several other techniques like fail2ban, spam assassin etc.. and might be your IP got blocked for some reasons. Try `tcptraceroute` ing to `mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net` from your network and from some other network to see whether only your network packets are dropped. One method available is to reach the other side, by sending mail to their postmaster.

Comment: I did a traceroute and it confirmed yahoo were blocking our IP in their firewall - after registering on their bulk sender list email is now flowing again.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have some sort of outgoing port 25 filter. Instead of pinging, try and telnet to the IP `188.125.69.79 25`.

It could be an issue with your ISP filtering, or maybe there is some sort of firewall level block on the other end, it would be odd that they are just dropping the traffic, and not rejecting your traffic explicitly..

A third possibility could be some sort of routing issues between you and those sites.

Comment: Hello Nick, thanks for the fast response.  Telnet from my server to 188.125.69.79 failed where as from my desktop it worked fine.  Does that suggest a firewall block at Yahoo?

Comment: Well, it could be a firewall issue, it could be a routing issue, do your desktop and server have the same ISP connection?

Comment: No, entirely separate connections for server and desktop. Would I be right in assuming that means it could be an issue with the datacentre dns resolvers listed under resolv.conf?

Comment: No, both those addresses are resolving correctly, you probably need to talk to your hosting provider, they're probably going to be able to give you more information.. possibly it's something they've implemented themselves..

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo bought a block of Iran IP's and changed to them for the MX for Yahoo.co.uk  If you use OFAC Sanctioned blocking check your IP list as these IP's were previously blocked by OFAC rules.  You will need to update the rules as these IP's are no longer Iranian owned.